# How to make PYQT gui update upon real time data acquasition? The objects considered being QLCD and Qlabel?

Tags: python, pyqt4, real-time

I do understand there is way using Threads by emplying Qtimer and yes I do want it to update on a real time basis. I have experienced changing of these object Qlcd and Qlabel upon pushing button how ever i want it to update upon itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answer from anyone I went in for digging and figured it out.

You need to add follwing code segment for repeated execution on a timely basis this helps the GUI update itself periodically for the stored variable data and update Qlable and QLCD widgets.

```
    self.timer.timeout.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL(self.READ_DATA))
    self.timer.start(51)
```

This upon trigger yield continus execturion as there is periodic signal generated.

Note: READ_DATA is the def i have declared in my program.